# Relación muchos a muchos y selección de campos Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un metodo en el controlador EventController que trae los datos de la tabla Event y los de la tabla Coin, ambas tablas tienen una relación entre ellas de muchos a muchos. La relación funciona y la consulta me trae todos las coin relacionadas con un evento, lo que yo quiero hacer es solo traer cierto campos (id y name) de la tabla coin y también algunos campos de la tabla Event, sé que se hace con un ->select(xx,xx) pero el problema da al implementarlo en la parte de with('coins), también he intentado con Event::with('coins:id,name') pero tampoco resulta.

¿Como puedo traer solo los datos mencionados anteriormente (tabla coin = id, name - tabla event = id, title, event_at)?

Esta es la consulta del controlador

```
$allMyEvent = Event::with('coins')
                        ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
                        ->where('status', '!=', 'RECHAZADO')
                        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                        ->get();
```

Ocupo Laravel 5.6

Answer (score 0):

Para limitar los campos que deseas de la relación, lo haces con una función anónima y ahí incluyes el select:

```
Event::with(['coins' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('campo1', 'campo2');
}])
...
```

Comment: `$allMyEvent = Event::with(['coins' => function ($query) {
                                $query->select('id','name');
                            }])
                            ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
                            ->where('status', '!=', 'RECHAZADO')
                            ->select('title', 'event_at', 'status')
                            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                            ->get();  ` Aun así me sigue arrojando error

Comment: ¿qué errores muestra?

Comment: Error de integridad, me alega por el ID de la tabla Coin, debe ser porque tengo dos select dentro de esa consulta

Comment: ¿cuál es el error exacto?

Answer (score -1):

Deberias poner el codigo completo de como tienes tus modelos, relaciones, controladores y el error exacto que te arroja para poder dar una respuesta mas acertada.

Todo lo que necesitas esta en esta parte de la documentacion.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

```
$books = App\Book::with('author')->get();

foreach ($books as $book) {
    echo $book->author->name;
}

$users = App\Book::with('author:id,name')->get();
```

Es necesario iterar la respuesta, agrega mas informacion a tu pregunta para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Gracias, lo tomare en cuenta.